# Get text from option field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select form with two options 'first' and 'second' and I would see changes on-time when I change the select option, but this code doesn't work :(

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Condition <span class="condition">---</span><br/> 
Select value <span class="value">---</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#test").change(function() {
    var test = $('#test option:selected').text();
    $('.value').text(test);

    if test == "first" {
      var condition = 1
    } else if test == "second" {
      var condition = 0
    }
    $('.condition').text(condition);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet. You should now be able to see the syntax error that's shown in the console. It's because your `if` condition syntax is wrong. You need to wrap the conditions in `()`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) for more information. I'm voting to close this as a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in if else statement

Try this

```
if (test == "first") {
     var condition = 1
} else if (test == "second") {
     var condition = 0
}
```

Comment: ok, my mistake, but it doesn't solve the problem: values with class condition and value don't update, when I pick up option from select form

Comment: Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bimalkumarh/6r5ry6z6/. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot! i have list without value when i add it's works...
    
    <select id="test">
        <option >first</option>
        <option >second</option>
      </select></td>

Comment: If it really helped you, please give an up vote. Thanks